# How can I convert Binary digits to integer in erlang?

Tags: erlang

Using `io_lib:format("~.2B~n", [A])` I can get a binary digits from a Integer value.

```
1> io_lib:format("~.2B~n", [150]).
["10010110"]
```

How can I reverse it and get a integer value from a binary digit ?

Comment: `list_to_integer("10010110", 2).`?

Comment: Thank you! 
By Noob

Answer (score 2):

> 2> list_to_integer("10010110", 2).
>
> 150

This can help others.